# Replication with Amazon RDS (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, database-replication, amazon-rds

Say we are using an *Amazon RDS (SQL Server) OLTP* database and reporting is facilitated through *(SSRS)* on an *Amazon AMI*. Would anyone know of replicating data from some of the tables on the *Amazon RDS* instances to the *AMI* instance in order to feed the reporting services?

Ideally we would like to use replication, but since *SQL Agent* is not available on *Amazon RDS (SQL Server)* this is not going to be possible.

If all else fails it looks like the only way to facilitate this would be to have the *OLTP* database also on an *Amazon AMI*.

Does anyone have any thoughts or recommendations on this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that `RDS SQL Server` does have is [Integrated Change Tracking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462(v=sql.105).aspx).  This is an incredibly efficient way to get changes (including deletes) from your `RDS SQL Server` (and even works with `SQL Express`).

What I typically do is have a scheduled process that runs a worker job to get the changes and pushes them to things like `AMI` or in some cases to another `SQL Server`.